# Form validation throws Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, integer given

Tags: php, laravel, request

I'm trying to submit a form that saves fuel details, it should check if  $vehicleMonitored  is an official or not. if its an official, it should check if the total fuel requested is not more than his weekly limit.
The code works fine because an error pops up if you try to request fuel that exceeds the fuel limit of a particular official but in a case that you request a fuel below the limit of the official, it doesn't save the data.   It throws the error below :

"Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, integer given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\app\Http\Controllers\FuelController.php on line 2044 ◀"

The error line 2044 points to the validator 'date' => 'required|max:255',

```
 public function store(Request $request)
 {


    $this->validate($request, [
        'date' => 'required|max:255',
        'liters' => 'required',
        'type' => 'required',
        'vehicle_generator'=> 'required',
        'recipient'=> 'required',
        'vehicle_type'=> 'required',
        'voucher' => 'required',
        'authorized_by'=> 'required',
    ]);

      $requestedFuel = $request->input('liters');
      $vehicleMonitored = $request->input('vehicle_type');

    if($vehicleMonitored == 'official'){

            $official  = $request->input('recipient');
            $sum =  DB::table('fuels')->whereBetween('created_at', [
                        Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(),
                        Carbon::now()->endOfWeek(),
                     ])->where('recipient',$official)->sum('liters');

            $Name = Officials::where(DB::raw('concat(Name," ",Surname)') ,$official )->get();
            $name = $Name->pluck('Fuel_Limit');
            $limit = $name->first();
            $over = $limit - $sum;

            // sum of liters plus requested liters 
            $request = $requestedFuel + $sum;
            // dd($limit);

            if($limit != null){

                   if($request >= $limit){

                        return redirect('fuels')->with('error',  $official ." has just "            .$over.'Liters remaining for the week ');
                                         }
            if($sum > $limit){

                        return redirect('fuels')->with('error',  $official .'  readched weekly fuel limit ');

                       }

       }

    }       

            //getting input of liters and reg. no:
            $myliters = $request->input('liters'); 
            $regs = $request->input('vehicle_generator'); 

            //saves to db
            Fuel::create($request->all());


              //return message
              if($vehicleMonitored == 'official'){

                 return redirect('fuels')->with('success', " You have sucessfully Supplied ".$myliters."L to ".$official. " for ".$regs);
                    }
               else{

                   return redirect('fuels')->with('success', " You have sucessfully Supplied ".$myliters."L to  ".$regs);

                   }
   }
```

Comment: is there anything before the `$this->validate` line of that controller method? that is the correct Controller from the error? ... and line 2044, your controllers are probably getting way too big :)

Comment: The if($vehicleMonitored == 'official') was above $this->validate.  i moved it below the validate and now it  says "Call to a member function input() on integer. the error points to  $myliters = $request->input('liters');

Comment: well obviously `$request` is an integer ... is there anything else above that line ... just put the EXACT code of that method above the line the error shows, don't remove things from above it

Comment: Can u post the route & full controller file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the `$request` variable in this line:

```
// sum of liters plus requested liters 
$request = $requestedFuel + $sum;
```

Simply use different variable name instead - there and in all the other lines that expecting this to be an integer:

```
// sum of liters plus requested liters 
$requestSum = $requestedFuel + $sum;
if($limit != null){
   if($requestSum >= $limit){
   ...
```

Validator uses should remain unchanged:

```
//getting input of liters and reg. no:
$myliters = $request->input('liters'); 
$regs = $request->input('vehicle_generator');
```